# How to get high score to submit/reportt to Game Center Leaderboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, game-center

I've scoured the internet for an answer to this. I have a leaderboard setup in iTunes Connect and it shows up on my game but the high score is never reported to the leaderboard.

here is the code I have for the leaderboard in my GameViewController.m

```
     - (void)authenticateLocalPlayer {
GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];

localPlayer.authenticateHandler = ^(UIViewController *viewController, NSError *error) {
    if (viewController != nil) [[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.rootViewController presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    else {
        if ([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].authenticated) {
            gameCenterEnabled = YES;

            [[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] loadDefaultLeaderboardIdentifierWithCompletionHandler:^(NSString *leaderboardIdentifier, NSError *error) {
                if (error != nil) NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
                else _leaderboardIdentifier = leaderboardIdentifier;
            }];
        }
        else gameCenterEnabled = NO;
    }
};
  }

    - (void)showLeaderboard {
GKGameCenterViewController *gcViewController = [[GKGameCenterViewController alloc] init];
gcViewController.gameCenterDelegate = self;
gcViewController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerStateLeaderboards;
gcViewController.leaderboardIdentifier = _leaderboardIdentifier;
[self presentViewController:gcViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
   }

- (void)gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish:(GKGameCenterViewController *)gameCenterViewController {
[gameCenterViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
```

and in my MenuScene.m and EndScene.m I have this code to show the best score which displays on screen as a label.

```
      _labelScoreBest = [[SimpleLabel alloc] initWithText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"bestScore"]] fontSize:MS_FONT_SIZE_LABEL_SCORE_BEST position:MS_POSITION_LABEL_SCORE_BEST colorByHEX:MS_FONT_COLOR_LABEL_SCORE_BEST andZPosition:MS_ZPOSITION_LABEL_SCORE_BEST];
```

which displays the best score on the screen. Hows do I get this to report to the leaderboard I have setup. My Leaderboard identifier is  defined by a pragma mark in my GlobalSettings.h as the the Leaderboard ID I made on iTunes Connect.

I hope all this makes sense and someone knows how to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  -(void)reportScore{
  if(gameCenterEnabled)
 {
int64_t newScore = (int64_t)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"bestScore"];

GKScore *score = [[GKScore alloc] initWithLeaderboardIdentifier:_leaderboardIdentifier];
score.value = newScore;

[GKScore reportScores:@[score] withCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}];
NSLog(@"Yo we're totally reporting the score now");
}
```

also added an NSNotification to my GameCenter code

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reportScore) name:@"reportScore" object:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to submit the highscore to GameCenter:

```
func addLeaderboardScore(score: Int64) {
    var leaderboardID = "YOURLEADERBOARDID"        
    let newGCScore = GKScore(leaderboardIdentifier: leaderboardID)
    newGCScore.value = score
    newGCScore.leaderboardIdentifier = leaderboardID
    GKScore.reportScores([newGCScore], withCompletionHandler: {(error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            print("Score not submitted")
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: I actually ended up doing something very very similar to your func which worked